# How to most easily convert a JSON with strings to JSON with arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I need to write a method called `public string PrepareForDeserialization(string json)` which converts a JSON string like this:

```
{"To":"name@company.com, name2@company.com, name3@company.com","CC":"namecc@company.com","BCC":""}
```

to a JSON string like this:

```
{"To":["name@company.com", "name2@company.com", "name3@company.com"],"CC":["namecc@company.com"],"BCC":[]}
```

Before I set out to solve this with `Substring()` and `Regex.Replace()`, is there some kind of easier JSON string-to-array converter that I could use, or what would be the easiest way to convert a serialized JSON string with strings, to a serialized JSON string with arrays?

Comment: From a Json perpective, you want to convert valid Json to valid Json... you will have to parse and transform your payload yourself. But honestly, it ain't *that* hard, is it?

Comment: you could serialise it back into an object, fish out the relevant strings, split them by comma into arrays, and the re-serialise the whole thing.

Comment: Deserialize it into an object (dummy class) then use that object to create another object (your actually class) and then just serialize it back.

Answer (score 3):

You should use some JSON Library (for instance [Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)) for that. This will take care of many pitfalls, you may miss, when manipulating JSON strings by hand.

```
var o1 = JsonConvert.Deserialize<JObject>(jsonstring);

//you can split by ' ' and ',' because email addresses won't contain any whitespaces. For other purposes you may need better splitting rules.
var to = o1.Value<string>("To").Split(new char[]{' ', ',"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var cc = o1.Value<string>("CC").Split(new char[]{' ', ',"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var bcc = o1.Value<string>("BCC").Split(new char[]{' ', ',"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var outstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new JObject{
   {"To", JArray.FromObject(to)},
   {"CC", JArray.FromObject(cc)},
   {"BCC", JArray.FromObject(bcc)},
});
```

Beware, there is no error handling. For instance this will throw, if the original string misses one of the three lists.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Newtonsoft.Json`

```
string strJson = @"{'To':'name @company.com, name2 @company.com, name3 @company.com','CC':'namecc @company.com','BCC':''}";
                dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strJson);
                Dictionary<string, string[]> val = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
                foreach (var prop in jsonObject)
                {
                    string name = prop.Name;
                    string[] datas = Convert.ToString(prop.Value).Split(',');
                    val.Add(name, datas);
                }

                string op = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(val);
```